# Sharing OneNote Notebook through API

Tags: onenote-api

As per the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-sharing-links) to "Create sharing links on OneNote entities", it appears the OneNote API only supports sectionGroups.

```
POST ../sectiongroups/{sectiongroup-id}/Microsoft.OneNote.Api.GetOrCreateAnonymousSharingLink
```

It however seems possible to create a link to a notebook (or section) with the OneDrive API

```
POST ../sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/createLink
```

Is there a problem with using the API this way (particularly as my notebooks don't have section groups)?