# How set onenote page as read only using onenote API

Tags: office365, onenote, onenote-api

I am using onenote graph API to create and update  notebook,sections,pages.

Know i want to make onenote page as read only using Onenote Graph API.

Please suggest PATCH or POST Request url to set onenote page as read only

Answer (score 1):

I think the only effective way of doing this is by creating a view only link to the Notebook.

The OneNote API only allows this for section groups as described at ["Create sharing links on OneNote entities"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-sharing-links)

```
POST ../sectiongroups/{id}/GetOrCreateAnonymousSharingLink with {"accessLevel":"View"}
```

Please see the post ["Sharing OneNote Notebook through API"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355091/sharing-onenote-notebook-through-api) for a different approach (using OneDrive sharing) to try and share either a whole notebook or just notebook section.

Comment: hi is their any other way let me know ,

hi codeye, To Over come above problem we used data-render-src option but we have problem with this one it is loading only once ,later changes(updates on my website) not showing in onenote page

can you see below question please help us end user need not edit the onenote page 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50733782/onenote-api-data-render-src-loading-only-once-from-the-webpage

Thanks,
Rammohan.